# how do I retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database into a listview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue about the getting the data from Firebase realtime database and putting it into the listview. I got all the data into the realtime database however, it doesnt let me retrieve it from there.

I also need to make it so it will take from a specific user via his unique uid.

```
public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ArrayList<Reminder> mReminderList;
    private ReminderAdapter mReminderAdapter;
    private ListView mReminderListView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
    }

}
```

ReminderAdapter:

```
public class ReminderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter\<Reminder\> {
private Context context;
private int resource;
private ArrayList\<Reminder\> remindersList;

    public ReminderAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Reminder> remindersList) {
        super(context, resource, remindersList);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.remindersList = remindersList;
    }
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }
    
        TextView reminderTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aTitle);
        TextView reminderdate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aDate);
        TextView reminderTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aTime);
    
        Reminder reminder = remindersList.get(position);
    
        reminderTitle.setText(reminder.getTitle());
        reminderdate.setText(reminder.getDate());
        reminderTime.setText(reminder.getTime());
    
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

```
public class Reminder {
String time;
String title;
String date;
String uid;
String key;

    public Reminder() {
        // Empty constructor required for Firebase
    }
    
    public Reminder(String title, String date, String time, String uid, String key) {
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
    
    public void setUid(String uid) {
        uid = uid;
    }
    
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    
    public void setKey(String key) {
        key = key;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

[image: Realtime Database for reference]

Comment: What is the exact reference you're attaching the listener to?

Comment: None of the code you shared read anything from Firebase, so I recommend getting started with the documentation for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data